# NGINX configuration for serving Laravel API at root as well as at subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Below is my configuration for serving Laravel API at endpoint http://api.example.com

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.com;
  index index.php index.html;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  root /var/www/public;


  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,Authorization';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
  }
}
```

But due to some reason I need to serve API at http://api.example.com/Laravel-project-1/public

And Laravel-project-1 folder also has resources folder that contains some images that too needs to be served at http://api.example.com/Laravel-project-1/resources/images/img.jpg

How to configure nginx to achieve it?

NOTE: right now if it's not possible to serve at http://api.example.com then it's okay. But it must be served at http://api.example.com/Laravel-project-1/public

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you change `root /var/www/public;` to `root /var/www/public/public;` your issue disappears.

The mistake you're probably making is that you've put your entire project into `/var/www/public` and that means that Laravel's `public` folder resides in that folder, which is your actual document root.

Comment: right now laravel source code is at /var/www directory and hence /var/www/public correctly points to laravel public/index.php

Comment: it's working fine at http://api.example.com | BUT i want to make it work at http://api.example.com/Laravel-project-1/public